Postman CLI: Cannot run "postman" in my terminal
I have installed postman cli via powershell with the command given in the documentation for windows 10.
But when I tried to run the command "postman" in the command prompt (powershell or others), I've got this error:
postman: The term "postman" is not recognized as a cmdlet name, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path exists, verify that the path is correct and try again.
To the character Line:1: 1
+ postman
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (postman:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException

I've tried different things: add "postman" to my path variables, reboot my computer after installing postman cli, using different terminals...
But none of these things worked.
I've npm 10.7.0 and node20.14.0 installed in my computer and newman works fine.
What can I do ?

Try following :  .\postman

yes thank you, it's worked
